# Defining the Euler class in different ways

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, sheaf-cohomology

Let $\pi: E\to M$ be a rank two real vector bundle over a manifold $M$. Bott and Tu defines the Euler class by:

1. giving $M$ a Riemannian structure,
2. taking a trivializing chart $U_\alpha$ of $M$,
3. defining an angle function on each chart $\theta_\alpha : U_\alpha \to \mathbb R$,
4. Defining functions $\varphi_{\alpha\beta}: U_{\alpha}\cap U_\beta \to \mathbb R$ by $\pi^*\varphi_{\alpha\beta} = \theta_\alpha-\theta_\beta$

and then doing a bunch of stuff to it. Note that $\varphi$ is not a Cech 1-cocycle since you can differ by multiples of $2\pi$ around a cycle. The Euler class $e(M)$ ends up being a 2-form in $H^2_{DR}(M). $

Given $\varphi$, another way to end up with a 2-form on $M$ is the following. Note that
$$0 \to 2\pi\mathbb Z\to \mathcal O_M \to \mathscr F \to 0$$ 
is an exact sequence of sheaves on $M$. Here, $\mathcal O_M$ is the sheaf of smooth real valued functions, $2\pi\mathbb Z$ is the sheaf of locally constant functions taking values in $2\pi\mathbb Z$ while $\mathscr F$ is the sheaf of smooth functions to $\mathbb R/2\pi (\cong S^1)$. We add two such functions $f,g: M \to \mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ by $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) \pmod {2\pi\mathbb Z}$.

The first map is simply the inclusion of locally constant functions into all smooth functions while the second map is the composition of a function $M\to \mathbb R$ with the covering space map $\mathbb R \to S^1$.

Exactness is obvious everywhere except at the last step. Working locally, we essentially need to show that we can lift a map $\mathbb R^n \to S^1$ to a map $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ but that follows by a homotopy lifting argument since $\mathbb R^n$ is simply connected.

We can take the derived functor cohomology of global sections of this exact sequence to get a boundary map $$\delta: H^2(M,\mathscr F) \to H^2(M,2\pi\mathbb Z),$$ 
note that derived functor cohomology matches cech cohomology in this case to realize $\varphi$ as an element in $H^2(M,\mathscr F)$.

Finally, consider the inclusion map $i: 2\pi\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$. This induces a map on cohomology $H^2(M,2\pi\mathbb Z) \to H^2(M,\mathbb R)$ and let the image of $\delta(\varphi)$ also be denoted $\delta(\varphi)$. Finally we identify $H^2(M,\mathbb R)$ with de-rham cohomology under the Poincare isomorphism to realize $\delta(\varphi)$ as a de-rham cohomology class.

Is is true that $\delta(\varphi)$ is in fact $e(M)$? If this is true, is there an easy proof? For instance, the Euler class is uniquely identifed as the pull back of the Thom class along the zero section. Maybe we can show that $\delta(\varphi)$ also satisfies this?

Also, is there a way to realize the global angular form along these lines?

Comment: Yes this is how the first chern class of a complex line bundle is sometimes defined in algebraic geometry. There's probably a slicker way, but if you write down cech cocycles for the cohomology groups in your LES and use the snake lemma to compute the connecting map, then youll see the explicit formula coming out

Comment: Could you expand on the connection to algebraic geometry a little? What is the corresponding exact sequence they use? And what is the analog of the angle function? If you have a reference, that would be great too.

Comment: It's called the exponential exact sequence: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_sheaf_sequence.  You take maps to C* instead of maps to S^1.